# How config letsencrypt ssl for non-www and www domain on the aws elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, lets-encrypt, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use https://github.com/tomyates/letsencrypt-install-elasticbeanstalk-single-instance/ to configure the letsencrypt SSL for aws elastic beanstalk.

My issue: https://github.com/tomyates/letsencrypt-install-elasticbeanstalk-single-instance/issues/2

I configured SSL for domain.com, it OK. (LE_SSL_DOMAIN = domain.com)
but when i run www.domain.com, browser error:
"Your connection is not private".

So, how to configure SSL simultaneously for domain.com and www.domain.com?
I tried:

```
-d "$LE_SSL_DOMAIN" -d "www.$LE_SSL_DOMAIN"
```

But it not working!

Help me.Thank all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
 sudo ./certbot-auto certonly -d "$LE_SSL_DOMAIN" --agree-tos --email "$LE_EMAIL" --webroot --webroot-path /var/app/current"$DOCUMENT_ROOT" --debug --non-interactive --renew-by-default
```

=> Update:

```
 sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --apache -d "$LE_SSL_DOMAIN" -d "www.$LE_SSL_DOMAIN" --agree-tos --email "$LE_EMAIL" --debug --non-interactive --renew-by-default
```